# Calculate a vector that moves a point away from a set of other points, so that the distance from all other points increases?

Tags: vectors

Wondering if there is a simple way to calculate an answer to this. I'm programming an app and points are randomly set (objects being dropped onto the 'ground'). I want to ensure that no one object is closer than X to any other. I've seen solutions like poisson disk sampling, but I feel like this kind of vector calculation shouldn't be too difficult?

After the objects are placed, an array is built with the distance from every point to every other point. (my function does not handle more than 8-10 points, this does not need to drop hundreds of trees in a forest, for example)

Now that I know which pairs of objects are closer together than the minimum threshold distance, I want to move one of the two objects away to the minimum distance. Calculating the vector away from the closest object is easy. But, for more than 2 objects, a move might put one now too close to a third object (or more).

Is there a (simple? Not god-awful?) way to take a set of 2D points and calculate a vector for one of those points that moves it farther away from all the other points, while keeping the distance to a minimum (If a point is directly between two others, it could move out from between them then away from both, but the shorter distance would be to move perpendicular to them)? Some way to "average" the individual vectors or... I don't know...? I'm asking here because I don't even know what terms to google for to figure out the problem.

Comment: if $d(x_1,x_2) < X$ where $d$ stands for the distance function and $X$ is your minimum threshold, you want them to satisfy $d'(x_1,x_2)=X$ where $d'$ is the new distance? If you are interested only in $d'(x_1,x_2) >= X$ it will be way more simple

Comment: Yes, >= X is fine. I'd prefer the distance moved to be as little as possible, but if the final distance is somewhat larger than X that works too. If I'm understanding your question. I'm a programmer and my math/algebraic notation deciphering are a bit rusty.

Comment: So if you didn't mind moving a lot, if $d(x_1,x_2)<X$ you can take $d_{max} = max(d(x,x_1))$ and move $x_1$ by $d_{max}$ to any direction you want. In order to minimize the movement, I need to think.. its gonna be harder